# Assigning Audiences in Lightning Communities

Tags: community, partner-communities, lightning-community

I am attempting to assign an audience in a lightning community but whenever I attempt to make the page based on both a profile and a record type I get this message "Record type criteria for Audience Auto/Hybrid PAS doesn’t work for cwbtool__CWB_Setup__c detail page. Edit the record type criteria." where Auto/Hybrid PAS is the name of the audience.  Does anyone know what "cwbtool__CWB_Setup__c" is?

Comment: cwbtool__CWB_Setup__c  looks like a csutom object

Comment: It looks like a managed package object with that prefix.